# Chrome Magnet Links (Xdg-open fail) - Popcorn time theft

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, mime-type

I have tried and tried and tried (i've never actually asked a Q Before, always figured it out)

But this is completly messed up so i urge you who have knowledge to help me.

On Chrome, Magnet links are being launched by Popcorn time instead of qBittorrent, which i am sure you can appreciate is highly unsatisfactory.

I have tried editing xdg-mime xdg-open the Popcorn-time.desktop entry to remove the magnet reference (in ~/.local/share/applications/Popcorn-time.desktop)

I have insured magnet exists in the qBittorrent.desktop. I have checked mimeapps.list in (~/.local/share/applications/) to use qBittorent.desktop

i have done everything that every guide on the planet has told me to do!

short of removing popcorntime completely, or switching away from chrome (both totally un-ideal) i have no clue what to do!

how do i set mime, to open magnet links (yes magnet links. not any extension file which can be set in properties)

Answer (score 1):

Like already told on IRC:

since gvfs-open now handles most mime types `gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet qBittorrent.desktop`  did set it to the wanted program qBittorrent.

Next time please stick to proper Facts and reduce all the swearing and ranting, so people can get a clue what the issue is and what you already tried to solve it.

Comment: Amazing answer. In Firefox, you can set default app, but in Chrome you are not able to. This worked and now magnet links and torrents are being opened with qbittorrent instead of pop corn time.